# Supporting authentication when using Java proxy class

Tags: java, proxy

I'm using java Proxy class and passing it to HttpURLConnection.openConnection().
Is there a way to provide authentication information (just like http.proxyUser and http.proxyPassword) to the Proxy class?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Authenticator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Authenticator.html) for that purpose:

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {

        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("login", "password".toCharArray());
        }
});
```

Comment: Will it affect the whole communication or just the relevant connection I'm opening?

Comment: @danieln Authenticator is static, so it is global to your application. But it will be invoked only if necessary. If you opened other connections that donnot require authentication, it won't be invoked.

Comment: So it is global to my application but not to the entire application server? (like http.proxyUser).
And what if I want different authentications for different connections?

Comment: @danieln inside the method `getPasswordAuthentication()` you can interrogate the Authenticator to find out for which request authentication is requested (`getRequestingURL()`, etc...)